# How to Fix Dipped Ceiling

Tags: drywall, light-fixture, ceiling, structural

I removed the chandelier in my living room to install recessed lighting. After looking at my installation, I noticed that the ceiling dips where the chandelier used to position, by about 2 inches. After measuring several points along the ceiling, the dip is a bit 'U' shaped (not just the spot where the chandelier used to be) with the ceiling measuring about 99in tall in the back and front and ~97in across the middle. In the picture below, the dipping is in the direction of the black reference line.
[image]

The drywall doesn't move when I push it up, and when I look inside the hole I can see that the drywall is still attached to the beam, so I'm thinking is the wood supports that run across the ceiling that are dipping (as opposed to the drywall coming off the ceiling).

[image]

What is a good solution to fix this?

I want to stop this from dipping more in the future.
Above this space is half finished (plywood, no drywall) attic used for storing stuff that I occasionally walk around when moving things.

Comment: It looks like you have some water damage in the celing.

Comment: first you need to find out if only  the drywall is bent, or if the wood that the drywall attaches to is also bent.

Comment: Put a 6 foot leveler against the ceiling, you might have loose or missing cross rafters.

Comment: What is above this room? Is it a 2nd story with a bedroom/bathroom? Is it attic space? A lot of the fix will be determined by what's above.

Comment: Above is an attic with plywood laid down across the floor.

Comment: Drywall? That looks like a wood product or a fiber board product that was used in the 30’s and 40’s maybe earlier.